# Regex trouble, combining negative and positive match

Tags: javascript, regex

I've had quite a lot of issues creating the perfect regex for my issue. Hopefully someone here can help me.
I'm trying to find all the variables in a SQL query.

As an example:

```
select *, 'string with :port in the text'
from table
where a = :variable
// and this is commented out :oldvariable
```

We used to find the variables using `r':(\w+)'`, to find all the words behind `:`.
However, I'd like to filter out the lines behind `//` and anything within `""` or `''`

The preferred output of the regex should be `:variable`.

`:port` & `:oldvariable` shouldn't be in there.

I can do the regex per line, so that might help in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example in php

```
<?php

$testo_pagina = "select *, 'string with :port in the text'
from table
where a = :variable
// and this is commented out :oldvariable";

if(preg_match_all('~^([\w\s\*,=]+)(:.+?)\b~im', $testo_pagina, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER))
{
    foreach ($matches as $key => $value)
    {
        print_r($value);
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => from table
where a = :variable
    [1] => from table
where a = 
    [2] => :variable
)
```

The idea here is to allow in the first part of the regexp "*([\w\s*,=]+)*" only the accepted charcters, so no **/** or **"** or **'** characters are allowed. Hope this helps.